# Javascript loop through object of many objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string JSON http response.

```
{
    "1537988400000": {
        "6495": ["18", "29"],
        "6490": ["34", "40"],
        "6500": ["7", "213"],
        "6505": ["13", "17"]
    },
    "1537992000000": {
        "6490": ["45", "87"],
        "6485": ["15", "4"],
        "6495": ["78", "222"],
        "6500": ["176", "141"],
        "6505": ["64", "94"],
        "6510": ["7", "53"],
        "6515": ["0", "1"]
    }
}
```

I want to parse it to a JavaScript object. The object must be structured so that I could get the numbers from the arrays. For instance, I choose `"1537992000000" -> "6495" -> [1]` and get '222'.

Here is my code:

```
var resp = this.responseText; // JSON string

var object = JSON.parse(resp);

for (var obj in object) {
    for (var a in obj) {
        alert(a[0]); // should return the first number in the array of an object
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't return numbers. It sends something like `0`,`1`..`9`,`10`.. (Seems like these are the indexes of each property's properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON pase logic is fine, you have mistaken here, `obj` is key

`for (var obj in object)`

> The object must be structured so that I could get the numbers from the arrays.

```js
var json={"1537988400000":{"6495":["18","29"],"6490":["34","40"],"6500":["7","213"],"6505":["13","17"]},"1537992000000":{"6490":["45","87"],"6485":["15","4"],"6495":["78","222"],"6500":["176","141"],"6505":["64","94"],"6510":["7","53"],"6515":["0","1"]}}

for(var i in json){
  for(var j in json[i]){
    console.log(json[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for(var a in obj){
> ```
>
> Seems like these are the indexes of each property's properties

Yes. [That is what `in` does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Use [`of` to loop over values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = '{"1537988400000":{"6495":["18","29"],"6490":["34","40"],"6500":["7","213"],"6505":["13","17"]},"1537992000000":{"6490":["45","87"],"6485":["15","4"],"6495":["78","222"],"6500":["176","141"],"6505":["64","94"],"6510":["7","53"],"6515":["0","1"]}}';

data = JSON.parse(data);



for (var obj in data) {

    for (var a in data[obj]) {
        console.log(data[obj][a]); 
    }
}
```